# How can I sum a group of sums? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, sum, inner-join

I have a query with a `sum` in it like this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.ID, SUM(Table2.[Number1] + Table2.[Number2]) AS SumColumn
FROM         Table1 INNER JOIN
                      Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID 
                    INNER JOIN
                      Table2 ON Table3.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE     (Table2.[Something] = 'Whatever')

GROUP BY Table1.ID,  Table2.[Number1] , Table2.[Number2]
```

and it gives me a table like this:

```
ID  SumColumn
67  1
67  4
70  2
70  6
70  3
70  6
80  5
97  1
97  3
```

How can I make it give me a table like this, where the SumColumn is summed, grouped by the ID column?

```
ID   SumColumn
67   5
70   17
80   5
97   4
```

I cannot `GROUP BY` SumColumn because I get an error (Invalid column name 'SumColumn'.) `COALESCE` doesn't work either. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

<strike>Just grouping by the ID gives me an error:</strike>

<strike>[Number1, Number2 and the other column names that I'm selecting] is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.</strike>

**EDIT 2**

No idea why but just grouping by Table.ID now seems to work. Thanks to all who posted the correct answer, I wish I could tick them all!

Comment: `SELECT Table1.ID ....GROUP BY Table1.Att1` should give an error that you can't select `ID` as it is not in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function- Are these both the same column and you forgot to change one in your example?

Comment: RE: Your latest edit that error is self explanatory isn't it? `SUM(Number1 + Number2)` is OK. `Number1, Number2` isn't.

Comment: `Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT
    Table1.ID, SUM(Table2.[Number1] + Table2.[Number2]) AS SumColumn
FROM         Table1 INNER JOIN
                      Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID 
                    INNER JOIN
                      Table2 ON Table3.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE     (Table2.[Something] = 'Whatever')
GROUP BY Table1.ID
```

I can't see why the above wouldn't work, unless you are not aliasing tables appropriately in the query, which is more of a syntax than logic mistake, but 'wrong' from the SQL engine's perspective regardless. Whenever SQL code doesn't work for me, **I simplify** *ad nauseam* my query until the reason for it failing becomes apparent. In that vein, I'd try:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(sumCol) as SumColumn
FROM (
    SELECT
        Table1.ID, (Table2.[Number1] + Table2.[Number2]) AS sumCol
    FROM         Table1 INNER JOIN
                          Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID 
                        INNER JOIN
                          Table2 ON Table3.ID = Table2.ID
    WHERE     (Table2.[Something] = 'Whatever')
)
GROUP BY Table1.ID
```

... and I'd allow any errors that show up from the following (and nested query!) to inform my further investigation.

Comment: @billynomates ... yup see the new and improved answer :-)

Comment: I have no idea what just happened. I started simplifying like you said by taking out the inner SELECT clause to see if that worked but added the GROUP BY. So exactly like you said in your first example. It works! Nothing that I can see is different from when I got the error, but thanks very much anyway. For anyone else reading this, I didn't need the nested SELECT at all and everyone who posted initially were correct.

Comment: @billynomates - can't tell you how many times "perfectly good" SQL doesn't run, but adjusting the code progressively like a detective ends up doing the job!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to group by just Table1.ID instead.

```
SELECT
    Table1.ID, SUM(Table2.[Number1] + Table2.[Number2]) AS SumColumn
FROM         Table1 INNER JOIN
                      Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID 
                    INNER JOIN
                      Table2 ON Table3.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE     (Table2.[Something] = 'Whatever')

GROUP BY Table1.ID
```

Since SUM() is an aggregate function, it will handle grouping the numbers together, you just need to specify how to group the other columns you want.

[UPDATE]

Demo Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1(
    ID      INT
)
CREATE TABLE #T2 (
    ID              INT,
    Something       VARCHAR(32),
    Number1         INT,
    Number2         INT
)
CREATE TABLE #T3 (
    ID      INT
)
DECLARE @Index INT = 0

WHILE @Index < 50
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Something VARCHAR(32) = ''

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
    IF @Index BETWEEN 0 AND 15
        SET @Something = 'Blah'
    ELSE IF @Index BETWEEN 15 AND 40
        SET @Something = 'Whatever'
    ELSE IF @Index BETWEEN 40 AND 50
        SET @Something = 'Bleh'
    INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES(@Index)
    INSERT INTO #T3 VALUES(@Index)
    INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(@Index, @Something, RAND()*100, RAND() * 100)
    INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(@Index, @Something, RAND()*100, RAND() * 100)
    INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(@Index, @Something, RAND()*100, RAND() * 100)
END

SELECT
    #T1.ID, SUM(#T2.Number1 + #T2.Number2) AS SumColumn
FROM         #T1 INNER JOIN
                      #T3 ON #T1.ID = #T3.ID 
                    INNER JOIN
                      #T2 ON #T3.ID = #T2.ID
WHERE     (#T2.Something = 'Whatever')
GROUP BY #T1.ID
```

Comment: Hmm, this worked for me.  I tried duplicating the error, but wasn't able to.  See my example above.

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
SELECT
    Table1.ID, SUM(Table2.[Number1] + Table2.[Number2]) AS SumColumn
FROM         Table1 INNER JOIN
                      Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID 
                    INNER JOIN
                      Table2 ON Table3.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE     (Table2.[Something] = 'Whatever')

GROUP BY Table1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a nested select?

```
SELECT ID, SUM(SumColumn) AS SumColumn
FROM (SELECT Table1.ID AS ID, SUM(Table2.[Number1] + Table2.[Number2]) AS SumColumn
      FROM Table1 
           INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID 
           INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.ID = Table2.ID
      WHERE (Table2.[Something] = 'Whatever')
      GROUP BY Table1.ID,  Table2.[Number1] , Table2.[Number2])
GROUP BY ID
```