# DB2 How do you use SUM function with Join

Tags: sql, join, db2, sum

DB2 info: z/OS v9.1

I am trying to create a query that selects different columns from different tables and one of the tables column's I need the sum of. For example:

```
    SELECT A.column1, B.*, SUM(C.Colum3) as col3
    FROM schema.TableA A, schema.TableB B, schema.TableC C
    WHERE A.column2 = B.column2 AND A.column1 = C.column1 
    GROUP BY A.column1;
```

The query doesn't work. I get an error:

```
    COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST IS NOT VALID.
```

I have tried different query examples like this one [How can I sum a group of sums? SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234669/how-can-i-sum-a-group-of-sums-sql-server-2008)

It is in sql server so that could be why it doesn't work. Not a lot of examples out there for DB2. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you'll get the same error in SQL Server, and every other major RDBMS too (excluding MySQL's quirk here): you have columns that aren't included in the `GROUP BY` clause, or part of an aggregate, so the system doesn't know what to do with them (MySQL returns a random row for those columns, I think, probably not what you want).

It's unclear what you're trying to get 'sum of sums' of, since you only list the one `SUM()`.  Assuming that `TableC` is the only table you need to aggregate, use a Common Table Expression (CTE), like so:

```
WITH Summed_TableC (column1, summedColumn) as (SELECT column1, SUM(column3)
                                               FROM TableC
                                               GROUP BY column1)
SELECT a.Column1, b.*, c.summedColumn
FROM schema.TableA as a
JOIN schema.TableB as b
ON b.column2 = a.column2
JOIN Summed_TableC as c
ON c.column1 = a.column1
```

Oh - never use the implicit join syntax.  You've nicely qualified which tables which columns come from, but if you don't, it's just plain confusing.  Avoid that by explicitly `JOIN`ing the tables, and their columns.